# tkinter filedialog save and docx tpl

Tags: python, tkinter

i am using a docx template along with tkinter and I am at a point where I want to save certain variables into the docx template I have created. If I specify the name of the file, all works well (doc.save(filename.docx)). However, I want to specify the filename using the `filedialog.asksaveasfile` function instead of calling out the name. I have tried several methods but I always get a blank docx file. Anybody ever try this by chance?

```
def summary_save():
    file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(
        mode="w",
        defaultextension=".docx",
        filetypes=(("DOCX", "*.docx"), ("All files", "*"))
    )
    if file is None:
        return

    context = {
        "doc_dn_name": designer_nameE.get(),
        "doc_pr_name": design_nameE.get(),
        "doc_sr_req": sr_entry.get(),
        "doc_td_num": t3d_entry.get(),
        "doc_nams_sub": names_entry.get(),
        "doc_chg_req": chg_entry.get(),
        "doc_imp_sc": preimp_notes_text_box.get(0.0, END),
        "doc_notes": notes_text_box.get(0.0, END)
    }
    doc.render(context)
    doc.save()
```

Comment: If you need the file name extracted from the path (selected by user when they select a file using your filedialog.asksaveasfile() ), you can try os.path.basename(<file path here>). Save that basename to a variable and now instead of providing the exact filename to the doc.save(filename.docx) function, you can pass this variable. 

If that doesn't work, please try to provide us a [Minimal reproducinle example](https://stackeroverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you Karthik, this greatly helped me after tinkering around for a bit. Below is the code that finally worked for me. Not the greatest looking but it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def summary_save():
    doc_path = resource_path("some file.docx")
    doc = DocxTemplate(doc_path)
    gsd_file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(
        mode="w",
        defaultextension=".docx",
        filetypes=(("DOCX", "*.docx"), ("All files", "*"))
    )
    if gsd_file is None:
        return

    name = gsd_file.name
    basename = os.path.basename(name)
    path = os.path.dirname(name)
    print(path)
    print(basename)
    context = {
        "doc_dn_name": designer_nameE.get(),
        "doc_pr_name": design_nameE.get(),
        "doc_sr_req": sr_entry.get(),
        "doc_td_num": t3d_entry.get(),
        "doc_nams_sub": nams_entry.get(),
        "doc_chg_req": chg_entry.get(),
        "doc_imp_sc": preimp_notes_text_box.get(0.0, END),
        "doc_notes": notes_text_box.get(0.0, END)
    }
    doc.render(context)
    doc.save(path + "/" + basename)
```